# How can i turn springboot rest endpoints to spring webflux reactive endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

bellow is my code, its written in springboot but im having trouble trying to write it in webflux. im using mono but im not sure how i can log info in mono or how i can return a responseEntity using mono either.

```
@GetMapping("/helloWorld")
public ResponseEntity helloWorld() {

    log.info("Entered hello world");

    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World");
}
```

there is not much i did in webflux but this is how far i got

```
   @GetMapping("/helloWorld")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity> helloWorld() {
//        log.info("Entered hello world in controller");
        Mono<String> defaultMono = Mono.just("Entered hello world").log();
        defaultMono.log();
//        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World ");

    }
```

Comment: Can you share your attempt in webflux? Also, you can try the tutorial from: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux

Answer (score 0):

Your function should return a `Mono` (single resource) or a `Flux` (collection resource).

```
@GetMapping("/helloWorld")
public Mono<String> helloWorld() {

    log.info("Entered hello world");

    return Mono.just("Hello World");
}
```

You should also make sure you have `spring-boot-starter-webflux` in your dependencies.

for example, maven pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@GetMapping("/helloWorld")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> helloWorld() {

   log.info("Entered hello world");

   return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World"));
}
```

May suggest reading the spring webflux [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html) as well Project Reactor [docs](https://projectreactor.io/).

Also if what you need is to log all the reactive stream I'd would suggest following code.

```
@GetMapping("/helloWorld")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> helloWorld() {       
    return Mono.just("Entered hello world in controller").log().map(s -> ResponseEntity.ok(s));
}
```

Some good spring webflux example can be found on internet, such: [Building Async REST APIs with Spring WebFlux](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-webflux/spring-webflux-tutorial/)